# Does mysql_fetch_object block other queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select query

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

The table is a myisam structure.

Am I right in thinking that once mysql_query on the sql has been executed and finished, no more blocking effects occur.

Specifically:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table WHERE key IN (..);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Once I do this:

```
while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
my stuff that takes a while
}
```

With the stuff that takes a while, will this have any impact on the mysql server performance? Slow things down, block things etc? Or is it the case that once the mysql_query has finished (which is quick by the way) there is no side effect of the stuff inside the while loop taking a few seconds each time for example?

Comment: You are right, nothing is blocked on the side of the mysql server, unless you block tables for your queries.

Comment: Unless another queries will be made inside the loop, once the query has finished the data will be stored in the $result variable and no further calls will be made to database related to the $result variable.

Comment: @Allkin Actually the `$result` variable does _not_ contain the data. It is a resource reference pointing to the data kept in the client implementation.